# Forcing EF to generate CAST in SQL string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I need to force Entity Framework to generate SQL with a `CAST(x as varchar(10))`. The one column is `varchar(10)` and the other is `nvarchar(100)`.

My LINQ looks something like this:

```
var results =
  db.User
    .Join(db.Stuff, 
       u => u.MetaTag, 
       s => s.StuffCode,
    (a, b) => a.StuffLongName)
```

I need SQL like this:

```
SELECT Stuff.StuffLongName 
FROM User
INNER JOIN Stuff
    ON   CAST(User.MetaTag AS VARCHAR(10))  = Stuff.Stuffcode
 ;
```

In case you are asking me "*Why?*", the SQL optimizer uses inefficient plans when the string is not a `varchar`.

I've tried EF model tags like this

```
...
[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
[MaxLength(10)]
public string MetaTag
...
```

The only change I was able to get thing I got EF to do was a `SUBSTRING(MetaTag,1,30)` ...but the optimizer didn't appreciate that.

My alternatives seem like a raw SQL string, or to use a stored procedure.

Comment: It seems MaxLength annotation enough in EF. Why do you think that cast will effect on performance?

Comment: What exactly do you consider to be an innefficient plan? I'm not sure why a cast would make it any better.

Comment: Are you tested both performance?

Comment: @Ikram - We have done exhaustive SQL plan analysis, and the CAST works like a charm.  Currently most of the code for this behavior is contained in stored procedures.  I am trying to move it into C#.  EF string generation doesn't include the CAST.

Comment: I agree with David. A conversion like this kills sargability. But I take your word for it that the conversion perform better, although to me it seems to be some lucky coincidence. Anyway, no, you can't force EF to do this.

Comment: @Tony - yes, lots of testing and the CAST is a lot better.  There are millions of records in both tables.

Comment: As Gert says, it does seem to be coincedence, or I might say guess it's a side effect. Perhaps you could show us both plans and we could help with a better query? You could share with [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) for example.

Comment: @Gert and DavidG   The SQL optimizer *sometimes* does hash matching instead, and row estimation and actual IO reads values are very different, depending on the tenant in the same database.  Actual execution times for large queries are visibly different.  Strange but true (in our environment).  Thanks for the answer

Comment: Do you by any chance observe the same if you use `CAST(... AS VARCHAR(11))`, or indeed any other expression that transforms `User.MetaTag` into something it isn't? The performance gain could be *because* it kills incorrect estimates in the optimizer, with the fact that the types of the expressions now match coincidental. (And if that's the case there may be subtler ways to get the same effect it in EF than `SUBSTRING`.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks - I saw the one column was actually a nvarchar, so as soon as I cast it to varchar(anything), it applies the efficient plan.

Comment: @zeeqzaq actually it's the cast that will eradicate performance. By applying the cast the optimizer won't be able to use any existing indexes. Post the table schema, any existing indexes and the resulting execution plan

Comment: @zeeqzaq neither EF nor SQL Server have any problems with Unicode/nvarchar. It's your own code that specifies that `MetaTag` is `Varchar`. On the other hand, mixing up varchar and nvarchar types is guaranteed to cause problems. *Maybe* the optimizer can pick the smallest table if you have up-to-date statistics, maybe not.

Comment: @zeeqzaq just fix your column types to use nvarchar throughout

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - thanks, but I can't change the DB schema - it's a legacy system.  The optimizer uses the same indexes in both cases, but does the nested loops on the wrong table (larger dataset)  without the cast.  I think I'll bypass EF for this single use-case, and probably use a sproc or TVF.

Comment: Changing the schema is the right way to do this. There might be pain associated with changing the schema; maybe you have to persuade your boss or so, or you might need to change scripts that you don't want to mess with, but I think it would be worth it. The solution to force the cast seems frail, it works for now, but who knows in the future; in newer versions of SQL or with more rows in the tables